# Select non-consecutive files using keyboard only

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In the windows explorer, how do you select non-consecutive files using keyboard only?

Environment: Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of ctrl and space and arrow keys.

Hold the ctrl key and use the arrow keys to navigate to the files you want to select. You should see a border of tiny gray dashed line on the file which you have reached to. Then select it by pressing space. On pressing space the file is selected.
Repeat until all required files are selected.